# Use gcc to compile multiple c files, ml (masm) to compile multiple assembly files and link with extern linker: Undefined reference to '__main'

Tags: c, gcc, ld, mingw32, exp

My ground problem is: I want to use a modern compiler to create through multplie steps a .exp file (special very old object file format from Phar Lab which starts with P3 as magic number and runs in 32-bit DOS)

So. I am using this line of code for compiling assembly files:

`ml /coff /c code.asm`

For multiple asm files to generate object files

And I am running
`gcc -m32 -c ccode.c -o ccode.o`

For multiple c-files to get all object files.

Afterwards I want to convert these object files with an converter so an old linker can use these object files to create an executable which runs in 32-bit DOS mode.

Even when I use ld with the not converted object files like this:

`ld code.obj ccode.o -o output.exe`

This returns multiple lines like this:

`ld: code.o:code.c(.text+0x18): undefined reference to '__main'` 
But there are lines where the undefined reference is not __main, but 'memcpy', 'free', '__mingw_vsprintf' and many more.

What can I do to get theses standard functions into the object files? Or are there other solutions?

I also tried using Open Wacom to get this old executable. But I could not install it on my windows 10 64-bit. Same with DJGPP, O could not run the needed go32-v2 it said it cannot be run in 64-bit windows... and I tried to find out if the exe file, generated by gcc when I directly compile all files, could be converted into the needed .exp file or if I can change it easily by hand. But I could jot find out how or if it is even possible

Comment: I recommend that you find a build of a cross-compiler for your target, or possibly build one yourself. Same with the standard library. There are plenty of tutorials and documentation available. And quite possibly already existing compilers and libraries for your target.

Comment: Like you noticed, the original 16-bit tools will not run directly on 64-bit Windows. That would require some kind of 2-level emulation, and MS decided not to bother supporting that.

Comment: There are some prebuilt DJGCC cross compilers at https://github.com/andrewwutw/build-djgpp or you can use that to build the cross compiler yourself. The programs built using the cross compiler won't run on 64-bit Windows, but you could run them in a 32-bit virtual machine or run them in DOSBox.

Comment: But the DJGPP could run in 64-bit Windows? If so, I will try that. Thank you

Comment: I've now tried installing it. First Problem: i don't know how to use this variant of gcc in mingw without always saying the path to djgcc. But it said "cannot execute 'cc1': CreateProcess: No such file or directory" in cmd after adding it to PATH. So I added cc1 from mingw folder to the bin folder of djgcc. Afterwards it could not find libgcc_s_seh-1.dll so i added it too by copying. Now there is a popup from cc1.exe that says "This application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"